# Partial content in .NET Core MVC (for video/audio streaming)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, streaming, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to implement video and audio streaming on my website (to enable seeking in Chrome) and I recently found out that .NET Core 2.0 apparently provides a relatively simple and recommended way of implementing this using `FileStreamResult`.

This is my simplified implementation of the Action that returns the FileStreamResult:

```
    public IActionResult GetFileDirect(string f)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(Defaults.StorageLocation, f);
        return File(System.IO.File.OpenRead(path), "video/mp4");
    }
```

The `File` method has the following (shortened) description:

> Returns a file in the specified fileStream (Status200OK), with the specified contentType as the Content-Type. This supports range requests (Status206PartialContent or Status416RangeNotSatisfiable if the range is not satisfiable)

But for some reason, the server still does not respond correctly to range requests.

Am I missing something?

---

### Update

Request sent from Chrome looks like this

```
GET https://myserver.com/viewer/GetFileDirect?f=myvideo.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Host: myserver.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
User-Agent: ...
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: ...
Cookie: ...
Range: bytes=0-
```

Response looks like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Fri, 09 Feb 2018 17:57:45 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 5418689
Connection: keep-alive

[... content ... ]
```

Also tried using the following command:
`curl -H Range:bytes=16- -I https://myserver.com/viewer/GetFileDirect?f=myvideo.mp4` and it returns the same response.

The HTML is pretty straightforward too.

```
<video controls autoplay>
    <source src="https://myserver.com/viewer/GetFileDirect?f=myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

The video DOES start playing - the user is only unable to seek the video.

Comment: Are you sure everything is correct client side? Can you post your request headers? What response does the server send back?

Comment: I have added more information to the question.

Comment: FileStreamResult used to work with dotnetcore but stopped after the update to dotnet 6. Did you see that issue after an upgrade?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There will be an enableRangeProcessing parameter added to the File method in version 2.1. For now, you need to set a switch. You can do this one of two ways:

In runtimeconfig.json :

```
{
  // Set the switch here to affect .NET Core apps
  "configProperties": {
    "Switch.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.EnableRangeProcessing": "true"
  }
}
```

or:

```
 //Enable 206 Partial Content responses to enable Video Seeking from 
 //api/videos/{id}/file,
 //as per, https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/pull/6895#issuecomment-356477675.
 //Should be able to remove this switch and use the enableRangeProcessing 
 //overload of File once 
 // ASP.NET Core 2.1 released

   AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.EnableRangeProcessing", 
   true);
```

See [ASP.NET Core GitHub Repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/pull/6895) for details.

Comment: Thank you. I set the Switch in Program.cs and now it works as intended!

Answer (score 26):

My answer is based on Yuli Bonner, but with the adaptations so that it answers the question directly, and with Core 2.2

```
 public IActionResult GetFileDirect(string f)
{
   var path = Path.Combine(Defaults.StorageLocation, f);
   var res = File(System.IO.File.OpenRead(path), "video/mp4");
   res.EnableRangeProcessing = true;
   return res;
}
```

This allowed for seeking in the browser.

Comment: Dude, trust me spent ages on this one. Lifesaver is the smallest word I could use to describe this.

Comment: Thank you.  This is the modern solution.  Most everything out there is still the old method of enabling the range processing from before 3.1

Comment: This should be top answer, its the modern solution, like the file streaming on express.js

Answer (score 0):

[Paulo Neves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59598916/15538104)'s answer is good enough, I provide more information for whom has bytes[] fileContent can do like this:

```
            FileStreamResult fileResult = new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(result), mapping.Mime);
            fileResult.EnableRangeProcessing = true;
            return fileResult;
```