# Stream Video from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, video-streaming, azure-blob-storage

I've been trying this out for a long time now, but can't seem to find the perfect way to do this documented (or demonstrated) anywhere

Here's my code so far; which has borrowed bits from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655868/streaming-video-from-azure-blob-storage) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48711209/partial-content-in-net-core-mvc-for-video-audio-streaming/48712243) amongst other places

```
[HttpGet("File/{id}")]
public IActionResult Index(int id)
{
    var file = Files(a => a.AttachmentId == id);
    if (file != null)
    {
        //using Azure.Storage.Blobs (v12)
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(config.GetConnectionString("azBlobConnection"));
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(file.BlobContainer);

        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(file.FileName);
        MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
        blobClient.DownloadTo(memory, null, new StorageTransferOptions {
            InitialTransferLength = 1024 * 1024,
            MaximumConcurrency = 20,
            MaximumTransferLength = 4 * 1024 * 1024
        });
        memory.Position = 0;

        string contentType;
        if (!new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider().TryGetContentType(file.FileName, out contentType))
        {
            contentType = "application/octet-stream";
        }

        Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.ContentDisposition, new ContentDisposition
        {
            FileName = file.FileName,
            Inline = true,
        }.ToString());

        return File(memory, contentType, true);
    }

    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    return null;
}
```

This finally works, and I get a seekable video in the browser that plays nicely.  My issue now if that the download is slow, and doesn't seem to be fully respecting the range headers coming from the browser.

Here's the network trace from Safari:

[image: safari network trace with range headers for video]

The above really feels like the file gets downloaded from Azure 3 times, despite the data returned to the browser; which will be making it slow and inefficient...

Also I notice the solution to what I'm probably after comes from the `HttpRange` parameter in this method: [`Download(HttpRange, BlobRequestConditions, Boolean, CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.download?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Specialized_BlobBaseClient_Download_Azure_HttpRange_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobRequestConditions_System_Boolean_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

My problem is I can't get a seekable response if I use the Download method, the only way I can get it to work is using `DownloadTo(stream)`, as above.

Whats the best way to do this...?

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you please tell me the error when you use `download` method?

Comment: No error, but the video isn't 'seekable'.  In Chrome the video loads, but it's not possible to skip through it.  Safari is worse as it won't load the video, just shows a crossed out play button

Comment: I'm in the same boat, you are even having some video with `Download` and `HttpRange`. For some reason I cannot have the video. While with `DownloadTo` it works.